# I would like guidance to create some directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

What I need:

Create a folder on the desktop, within that folder create another called "img" and inside img create "home".

The way I managed to do it, But I know it's not the ideal way ... I'm still learning, thank you for your patience!

Any suggestions to improve this?

```
var nome = 'teste';
const dir = `C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/${nome}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdir(dir, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            dirImg = dir+'/'+'img';
            fs.mkdirSync(dirImg)
            fs.mkdirSync(dirImg+'/'+'home')
            console.log('Sucess')
        }
    });
}else{
    console.log(`File $ {name} cannot be created because it already exists!`)
}
```

Comment: Why mix asynchronous functions with synchronous functions?  Usually, you want one or the other for everything.  If this is a server, you need all asynchronous (unless it's only startup code) so you don't wreck your server's scalability.  If this is just your own personal script, you can make everything synchronous and simplify the programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) has a `recursive` option, so:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdir(`${dir}/img/home`, {recursive: true}, (err) => {
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log('Sucess')
        }
    });
}else{
    console.log(`File $ {name} cannot be created because it already exists!`)
}
```

---

Side note: It's generally not a good idea to check for existence before creating. Instead, just go ahead and try to create it. From the documentation:

> Calling `fs.mkdir()` when path is a directory that exists results in an error only when recursive is false.

So:

```
fs.mkdir(`${dir}/img/home`, {recursive: true}, (err) => {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log('Sucess')
    }
});
```